# libc6-i386 installation on Yocto build

Tags: java, jvm, embedded-linux, yocto

I'm trying add a Java installation on my Yocto build. I would like to run on my embedded system a Java application I developed but I can't correctly install Java.
When I try to run java I get the following:

```
./java: No such file or directory
```

I googled for a solution and found that I need to install libc6 32 bit version.
I proceeded to modify my local.conf file as following:

```
MACHINE ??= "intel-corei7-64"

require conf/multilib.conf
MULTILIBS = "multilib:lib32"
DEFAULTTUNE_virtclass-multilib-lib32 = "x86"

DISTRO ?= "poky"
PACKAGE_CLASSES ?= "package_rpm"
SDKMACHINE ?= "x86_64"
EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats image-mklibs image-prelink"
PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
BB_DISKMON_DIRS = "\
    STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
    STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
    ABORT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
    ABORT,/tmp,10M,1K"

PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-qemu-native = " sdl"
PACKAGECONFIG_append_pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"

CONF_VERSION = "1"

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL = " lib32-glibc"

CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "opencv opencv-samples libopencv-core-dev libopencv-highgui-dev libopencv-imgproc-dev libopencv-objdetect-dev libopencv-ml-dev"
```

But i get this error:

```
Build Configuration:
BB_VERSION        = "1.32.0"
BUILD_SYS         = "x86_64-linux"
NATIVELSBSTRING   = "universal-4.8"
TARGET_SYS        = "x86_64-poky-linux"
MACHINE           = "intel-corei7-64"
DISTRO            = "poky"
DISTRO_VERSION    = "2.2.1"
TUNE_FEATURES     = "m64 corei7"
TARGET_FPU        = ""
meta              
meta-poky         
meta-yocto-bsp    = "morty:924e576b8930fd2268d85f0b151e5f68a3c2afce"
meta-intel        = "morty:6add41510412ca196efb3e4f949d403a8b6f35d7"
meta-oe           = "morty:fe5c83312de11e80b85680ef237f8acb04b4b26e"
meta-intel-realsense = "morty:2c0dfe9690d2871214fba9c1c32980a5eb89a421"

Initialising tasks: 100% |#####################################################################################################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:22
NOTE: Executing SetScene Tasks
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
ERROR: rmc-1.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: rmc: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /usr/lib
  /usr/lib/librmclefi.a
  /usr/lib/librsmpefi.a
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
rmc: 3 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: rmc-1.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: rmc-1.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/dalben/WorkingBuild/poky/filec/tmp/work/corei7-64-poky-linux/rmc/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.16424
ERROR: Task (/home/dalben/WorkingBuild/poky/meta-intel/common/recipes-bsp/rmc/rmc.bb:do_package) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 2954 tasks of which 2937 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/dalben/WorkingBuild/poky/meta-intel/common/recipes-bsp/rmc/rmc.bb:do_package
Summary: There were 3 ERROR messages shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Updated question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093838/java-installation-error-on-yocto-build).

Comment: As answered by Charles C. I apperently don't need to install libc6 lib.
Still I can't get my build to work. Will post more info in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your information, you will need to do a lot of work in putting Java into your image.

Your current image does not have any java related programs installed since I do not see `meta-java` in your compile process.

`CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL` is restricted to  [OE Core images](https://github.com/openembedded/openembedded-core/blob/master/meta/classes/core-image.bbclass); So if you have your own image recipe, the variable will does not work unless you inherit `core-image.bbclass`

Here is an example on putting "openjdk-7-jre" to the image: http://wiki.hioproject.org/index.php?title=OpenHAB:_WeMo_Switch

The key elements are:  [meta-java](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-java/), [meta-oracle-java](http://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layer/meta-oracle-java/) .
You will need to add them to your `conf/bblayers.conf`

```
BBLAYERS = " \
 ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-java \
 ${BSPDIR}/sources/meta-oracle-java \
"
```

In `conf/local.conf`, add this line to install openjdk-7-jre.

```
IMAGE_INSTALL_append = " openjdk-7-jre "
```

To add more on what you need, check on https://layers.openembedded.org/layerindex/branch/master/layers/

Comment: So I don't need to install the 32bit version of libc6?

Comment: Ok. I still can't get it to work, I'm opening a new question because this was answered.